# What's the best way to populate List<Object>?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, javabeans

There are 100 Branch objects in `List<Branch>` and already set branchId (001 to 100).I want to use `List<Branch>` to make a report with iReport.

But now my data all in the other List `List<Temp>` and The data is duplicate in `List<Temp>` .

```
branchId  firstName  lastName type         number
-------------------------------------------------------------
005         Amy        Lee     home        1234567
005         Amy        Lee     office      9999999
005         Amy        Lee     cellphone   1111111
005         John       Lin     home        1231231
067         Louis      Tsai    home        0809097
....
```

**My Question is as follows:

I need use `List<Temp>` convert to `List<Branch>` and if branchId not match in `List<Branch>`, just set `List<User>` null.  How can I do?**

```
public class Temp{

    private String branchId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String type;
    private String number;

    //getter and setter here

}
```

Branch Bean

```
public class Branch {

    private String branchId;
    private List<User> user;

    //getter and setter here

}
```

User Bean

```
public class User {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<Phone> phones;

    //getter and setter here

}
```

Phone Bean

```
public class Phone {

    private String type;
    private String number;

    //getter and setter here

}
```

Thanks a lot.

**-----------update----------------**

As you can see, below is what I need it look like: 
There are Amy Lee and John Lin sorted under branchId 005 and a different branchId 067 will show in different page.With the same branchId, ex: 005 Amy Lee, there are 3 kinds of numbers under her. Now, report need retrieve `List<Branch>`. That's the reason why I need loop `List<Temp>` and set  `List<Branch>`. Is there any way that I can make it?

```
005
-----------------------------------
Amy        Lee     home        1234567
                   office      9999999
                   cellphone   1111111
John       Lin     home        1231231
```

next page

```
067
-----------------------------------
Louis      Tsai    home        0809097
```

Comment: I am not sure why you are doing this is it too order everything? If it is why don't you just use branch and use a sorted lists, like a set or a bag. Having 3 separate List's isn't efficient at all in most cases. And instead of having a branch item with jsut a string and a list you can have a HashMap<string, List<Temp> or HashMap<string, Temp[]>

Comment: @YaWang Thank you for your reply, I just update my question.Cause report need retrieve List<Branch>.

Answer (score 0):

I would replace those Lists by maps if I were you, and the usage is going to be kind of like this.

```
List<temp> t; 
for (temp t : tempList) { 
    if ((Branch b = branchMap.get(t.getBranchID)) != null) { 
        if ((user u = b.getUsers.get((t.getFirstName() + t.getLastName()) != null) { 
            user.getPhonse.add(new Phone(t.getPhoneType(), t.getPhoneNumber())) 
        } 
    } else { 
        List<Phone> phonse = new ArrayList<Phone>();
        phonse.add(new Phone(t.getPhoneType(), t.getPhoneNumber()));

        Map<String,String> users = new hashMap<String,String>();
        users.put(t.getFirstName() + t.getLastName(), new user(t.getFirstName(), t.getLastName(), phones);

        branchMap.put(t.getBranchID, new Branch(t.getBranchID(), new hashMap<String,String>().put(t.getFirstName() + t.getLastName(), new user(t.getFrstName(), t.getLastName(), new List<Phone>)))))) 
    } 
}
```

Comment: this code is incomplete I know, I am just trying to give you the slightest idea of how to do this, though this code might work with some extra effort form you, don't hesitate to ask if you don't understand the general idea behind this solution